# WCF - Error Handling - Creator of this service did not specify a Reason

Tags: wcf, fault

There are lot of threads with the same error but I could not find a suitable answer so putting it again.

I have a wcf service and I have error handling in place and when I test the service from the wcftestclient all I get is this error info and not the original error that actually occurred.

**The creator of this fault did not specify a Reason. Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc) at ...**

I am not sure why its not returning me the actual error. My error handling code is given below.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the holidays.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>List<HolidayProfile></returns>
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionFaultContract))]
    List<HolidayProfile> GetHolidays();


public List<HolidayProfile> GetHolidays()
    {
        List<HolidayProfile> holidayProfileList = new List<HolidayProfile>();
        try
        {
            customerBL = new CustomerBL(new CustomerRepository());
            holidayProfileList = customerBL.GetHolidays();
        }
        catch (CustomException ex)
        {
            throw new FaultException<ExceptionFaultContract>(DBHelper.MapException(ex));
        }
        return holidayProfileList;
    }
```

I have used two custom Exception classes here. One which is derived from Exception and other is the one which will be passed between the service and client

```
/// <summary>
/// Class CustomException.
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="System.Exception" />
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error code.</value>
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error detail.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error detail.</value>
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error number.</value>
    public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and another which is the datacontract.

```
/// <summary>
/// Class ExceptionFaultContract.
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class ExceptionFaultContract : Exception
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error code.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error code.</value>
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error number.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error number.</value>
    [DataMember]
    public int ErrorNumber { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the error description.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The error description.</value>
    [DataMember]
    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }
}
```

**My method in the dataacess.**

```
 public List<HolidayProfile> GetHolidays()
    {
         Initializations          
        try
        {
            Code here...
        }
        catch (OracleException ox)
        {
            throw (DBHelper.HandleOracleException(ox));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (DBHelper.HandleException1(ex));
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
                connection.Close();
            if (command != null)
                command = null;
            if (dataAdapter != null)
                dataAdapter = null;
            dataSet.Dispose();
        }
        return holidayProfileList;
    }
```

**My helper class which does the mapping.**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex">The ex.</param>
    /// <returns>ExceptionFaultContract.</returns>
    public static CustomException HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        CustomException customException = new CustomException();
        customException.ErrorDescription = ex.Message;
        return customException;
    }       
    /// <summary>
    /// Maps the exception.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ex">The ex.</param>
    /// <returns>ExceptionFaultContract.</returns>
    public static ExceptionFaultContract MapException(CustomException ex)
    {
        ExceptionFaultContract exceptionFaultContract = new ExceptionFaultContract();
        exceptionFaultContract.ErrorCode = ex.ErrorCode;
        exceptionFaultContract.ErrorNumber = ex.ErrorNumber;
        exceptionFaultContract.ErrorDescription = ex.ErrorDescription;
        return exceptionFaultContract;
    }
```

I m getting an error if I m using the ExceptionFaultContract to be returned from data access ("Error : should be a type derived from exception") and If I try to derive the same from Exception another error saying it cannot be both serializable and derived member or something like that..

I tried lot of things nothing is clear to me...could somebody please help.